# stackoverflow error on testing chromedriver on selenium

Tags: java, json, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

unable to instantiate webdriver instance for chrome. 
getting stack overflow error

### Listing 1 - using chromedriver

```
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver "E:/selenium/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");                
  DesiredCapabilities dc=DesiredCapabilities.chrome() ;
 System.out.println("set dc change");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(dc);
```

### Listing 2 - Chrome Driver service.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

   service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
             .usingDriverExecutable(new File("E:/selenium/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"))
             .usingPort(9515)
             .build();
         service.start();

         driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(),
                 DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
```

In both cases , stackoverflow exception is coming .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:988)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)
    at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)
```

I am using java-json.jar from java2s.com . 
I did not find any java-json.jar http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/

Some of the jar version  which i am using are listed below. 
All jars have been added manually into java build path

- selenium-api-3.4.0.jar
- selenium-chrome-driver-3.0.0.jar
- selenium-common-2.0b1.jar
- selenium-remote-common-2.0b1.jar
- selenium-remote-driver-3.4.0.jar
- selenium-support-3.4.0.jar

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question to include the 'bottom' of the stacktrace (i.e. everything after the three lines in `org.json.JSONObject` that repeat)?

Comment: @Luke **Last 3 lines** are repeated all the way down 
         at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
 at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)
 at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)

Comment: I have this same issue did you ever find a solution?